# Apply "setQuotePrefixed(true)" automatically

Tags: java, apache-poi

We have a project with quite a big code base and I'm looking for a way to implement a security-feature, where the `setQuotePrefixed(true);` style-flag is automatically applied to cells with content that starts with a `=` (as these contents would be interpreted as formulas once Excel is opened and the cell value is changed or pressed enter on unchanged).

We already have a class that produces "clean" instances of XSSFWorkbook (with some core properties nilled out). There I've implemented a method to create autofixing workbooks, but this is not working for streaming workbooks (SXSSFWorkbook), because these are already streamed out before the "commit" method is called.

Do you know how I could implement such a behaviour for SXSSFWorkbooks?

Here's my code for XSSFWorkbooks:

```java
public static XSSFWorkbook createCleanXSSFWorkbook(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(is){
        @Override
        protected void commit() throws IOException
        {
            applySafeCellStyles(this);
            super.commit();
        }
    };
    cleanXSSFMetaInformation(wb);
    return wb;
}

private static void applySafeCellStyles(Workbook wb)
{
    int sheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
    Map<CellStyle, CellStyle> styleToSafeStyleMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < sheets; sheetNumber++)
    {
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        for (Row row : sheet)
        {
            for (Cell cell : row)
            {
                if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING)
                {
                    String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    if (cellValue.startsWith("="))
                    {
                        CellStyle thisCellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
                        CellStyle safeCellStyle = styleToSafeStyleMap.get(thisCellStyle);
                        if (safeCellStyle == null)
                        {
                            safeCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                            safeCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(thisCellStyle);
                            safeCellStyle.setQuotePrefixed(true);
                            styleToSafeStyleMap.put(thisCellStyle, safeCellStyle);
                        }
                        
                        cell.setCellStyle(safeCellStyle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the `cell.setCellValue` calls to check the value  and apply the safe style whenever a new cell is populated?

Comment: Yeah but how? I could of course write a utility method that does that checking and applies the style, but i'd have to implement it all over our codebase, and if a new dev creates an excel-export he's prune to forget about this.

Comment: Have your own wrapper around SXSSF that implements this, and make sure that your developers only ever pull in your version and not the vanilla Apache POI?